# Show required user profile fields after the account is verified during first login

Tags: 7, users

The user can register with their username, email and password. Once the account verifies their account i need to show custom required fields like age, sex , profession to be filled.

[Complete profile](https://drupal.org/project/complete_profile) comes in handy to force filling of required fields.

But, if i mark the fields as required they show on the registration form. Is there a way to hide the required fields of the user profile in the registration form???

I tried [Field Permission](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) and removed permission for anonymous users to see the fields. Though it doesn't show the fields, once the form is submitted it returns the hidden fields as required.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I may need to do this and the only way I can think of is to create a separate form that registers users programmatically and as soon as the users arrive to the site to use Complete profile .

Answer (score 2):

1. Use this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/required_by_role
2. In rules you can add rule "**After login user**" -> Do: redirect to "**profile edit**"

Or add rule if user **view content** -> **redirect** to "profile edit" and show status message "**required fields need to be filled**"